# Ruby - Regex Extraction of a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to extract the content of a string that is formatted in the following manner:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                            document.viewData = THE INFORMATION I WANT 
</script> some other stuff
```

Any ideas on how to implement that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part do you mean to be the content?

Comment: Are you saying the string has the embedded line breaks, or are these scanned as separate strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text data:

```
text = <<-_TEXT_
    <script type="text/javascript">
                            document.viewData = THE INFORMATION I WANT
</script> some other stuff
_TEXT_
```

Setup a regular expression

```
re = /document\.viewData = (.*)/
```

apply it to the text and get the result

```
result = (text.match re)[1]    
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse <<-_XML_
<script type="text/javascript">
                            document.viewData = THE INFORMATION I WANT 
</script> some other stuff
_XML_

doc.at('//script').text.strip.split("=").last
# => " THE INFORMATION I WANT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how strict you can be, this can do the work (the result in the match group):

```
<script type="text\/javascript">\W+document.viewData =\s+([^<]+)\W+\s+<\/script>
```